# Repressurise Baxi boiler

Tags: boiler

I'm having trouble repressurising my Baxi boiler. No matter what I do the blue valve on the left just won't budge! Tried pushing it towards me and the wall. Any ideas?[image: here is my boiler]

Comment: use a marker pen to uniquely identify all of the components ... take lots of pictures ... take the pipes apart ... remove the valve ... replace or repair valve ... reassemble using pictures as a guide

Comment: I'm sorry but that's beyond me to take pipes apart. I'm not an engineer, I don't know the first thing about pipes

Comment: did you actually turn the blue handle before?

Comment: First time trying to do anything with the boiler

Comment: Push it towards the wall (turn it clockwise). Scale build up can make them very stiff - sometimes a wiggle can help. If not you may be able to remove the blue handle and use a small spanner to turn it. Failing that, call a plumber to free it or replace the filling loop.

Comment: @Louise two questions ... are you able to turn the right side blue handle? ... what is printed on the left side blue handle?

Comment: I can't. It won't move.

Comment: I can't see anything on the side?

Comment: I can turn the one on the right

Answer (score 1):

Use a short Philips screwdriver to undo the screw that holds the blue handle. Remove the handle, then use a spanner (possibly 7mm) to turn the square head of the valve where the handle used to be. The length of the spanner might give you enough leverage to get the valve unstuck (but don't go crazy on it as you might pull other fittings out of place and cause a leak).

You'll want to turn anticlockwise which means pulling the spanner down or towards you. As others have indicated, it'll only do a quarter turn.